# What is the alternative to SET XACT_ABORT ON in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL server, we are using `SET XACT_ABORT ON` inside the stored procedure. So, in the Postgres is what is the alternative `SET XACT_ABORT ON` statement.

**SET XACT_ABORT:**

When `SET XACT_ABORT` is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

When `SET XACT_ABORT` is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF. OFF is the default setting in a T-SQL statement, while ON is the default setting in a trigger.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry now I have updated the question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.

This is the default and only behavior in PostgreSQL (unless you are using a savepoint), so there is nothing much you have to do. A difference is perhaps even after an error, PostgreSQL won't terminate the transaction block automatically, so you still have to issue `ROLLBACK`. This is so that the remaining statements after the error don't get executed in their own transaction, but get ignored along with the erroneous statement.

Comment: ok so, in postgres we don't have to do this as by default postgres behaves like SET XACT_ABORT ON(MSSQL) feature that is what you're referring right?

Comment: I have just posted a separate question regarding PostgreSQL transactions. I think there’s a difference here: PostgreSQL doesn’t appear to terminate the transaction until you run a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` separately. MSSQL does. Is that correct?

Comment: @Manngo I cannot speak about Microsoft SQL Server, but you describe PostgreSQL's behavior correctly.